# Nested JSON call giving: Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression

Tags: javascript, json, nested, syntax-error

I hope this isn't a duplicate, I've found similar questions but none that show exactly my issue.

I'm working in Nomics API, which is a cryptocurrency API. Here's the API request I'm making: https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=2018-09-demo-dont-deploy-b69315e440beb145&ids=BTC,ETH,LTC,XRP,DOGE

I'm trying to get the variable `${coin.1d.price_change}...` but it's console logging the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression

This works with non-nested JSON, for example `${coin.price}...`

The code I'm working on is:

```
function getValueChanges() {
    return fetch(proxyurl + "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=2018-09-demo-dont-deploy-b69315e440beb145&ids=BTC,ETH,LTC,XRP,DOGE").then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    return json;
  });
}

getValueChanges().then(function(result) {
  result.forEach(coin => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = coin.currency;

      const p = document.createElement('p');
      //coin.description = coin.description.substring(0, 300);
      // !!!! ERROR IM TALKING ABOUT !!!! //
      p.textContent = `${coin.1d.price_change}...`;
      // !!!! ERROR IM TALKING ABOUT !!!! //

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
      card.appendChild(p);

      console.log(coin.currency + ": " + coin.price);
    });
  //console.log(result);
});
```

Basically I'm making cards with the cryptocurrency information, I have put some comments around the statement passing the error.

Thanks, if I have done something wrong (this my first question) lmk, when I get my next paycheck I'll buy you a coffee.

Comment: `coin.1d` is a syntax error. For property names to be used with the `.` operator, they must be valid identifiers, and identifiers cannot start with a digit.

Comment: You can use `${coin['1d'].price_change}` instead

Comment: The JSON uses 1d as a attribute, how would I work around this?

Comment: See just-posted additional comment

Comment: Ahh tysm, whats your paypal/venmo? Im makin a crypto app but i dont do crypto ahaha

Comment: We work for free around here :)

Comment: Thank u :) To show my gratitude I'll try to answer questions for other users

Answer (score 1):

Pointy figured it out, very simple error

coin.1d is a syntax error. For property names to be used with the . operator, they must be valid identifiers, and identifiers cannot start with a digit.

You can use ${coin['1d'].price_change} instead